# Generate table with define SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have 2 tables to manage generate real table with table name and column:

- Table (TableID, TableName)
- TableColumn (ColumnID, ColumnName, Datatype, Size)
  --(Size is size of nvarchar type, ID is auto identity(1,1))

Table:

```
TableID    TableName
----------------------
1          TopCity
```

TableColumn:

```
ColumnID    ColumnName    DataType    Size
-------------------------------------------
1           CityID        int         null
2           CityName      nvarchar    100
```

I want to write a procedure to create real table `TopCity` (CityID, CityName) with column details as described in `TableColumn`.

```
CREATE TABLE TopCity
(
    CityID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    CityName NVARCHAR(100)
)
```

Comment: yup, you can do it

Comment: As you’ve written this question, it’s very unclear what you are asking. Seems you are asking someone to write this procedure for you? What have you tried yourself?

Comment: You should have foreign key of `TableID` in `TableColumn` to identify the columns table wise.

Comment: You've created tables so you can define table metadata in them so you can create tables. This seems a little over engineered. This might not be the great idea that you think it is

Comment: I have tried a lot but could not. I had trouble finding a way to join the column definition lines together to create the query. Do it by Susang way, I was successful. COALESCE is the key of problem. Tks Susang!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TRY THIS:** You must do some changes as `TableID` as foreign key in `TableColumn` to identify the columns table wise. It would better to use `TableID` and `ColumnID` as `identity` column. If you have those columns `identity` then use `WHILE` loop as below otherwise we should use `CURSOR`.

1- Table once created should be marked as `created` so it should not run again, we should create `flag` column in `Table` to maintain it and update after creation of every table

2- If you want to create only one `table` then we don't need any `LOOP`

3- For the `identity` column it whould better to mention in `Datatype` column of `TableColumn` table as below

```
CREATE TABLE #Table(TableID INT IDENTITY(1,1), TableName VARCHAR(100))

CREATE TABLE #TableColumn(ColumnID INT IDENTITY(1,1), 
    TableID INT, --Add foreign key constraint
    ColumnName VARCHAR(100), 
    Datatype VARCHAR(50), 
    Size INT)

INSERT INTO #Table VALUES
('TopCity')

INSERT INTO #TableColumn VALUES
(1,'CityID','int identity(1,1)',null),
(1,'CityName','nvarchar',100)

DECLARE @ColumnList VARCHAR(1000), @TableName VARCHAR(100), @i INT = 1, @j INT = 0
SELECT @j = COUNT(*) FROM #table

WHILE @i <= @j
BEGIN
    SELECT @TableName = TableName FROM #Table WHERE TableID = @i
    SELECT 
        @ColumnList = COALESCE(@ColumnList + ', ', '') + '' + 
                    tc.ColumnName + ' ' + 
                    tc.Datatype + '' + 
                    CASE WHEN tc.Size IS NULL THEN '' ELSE CONCAT('(',CAST(tc.Size AS VARCHAR),')') END
    FROM #Table t
    INNER JOIN #TableColumn tc ON tc.TableID = t.TableID
    WHERE t.TableName = @TableName

    --SELECT @TableName, @ColumnList

    EXEC('CREATE TABLE  ' + @TableName + ' (  ' + @ColumnList + ' )')

    SET @i = @i + 1

END
```

Comment: Thanks Susang, you are master.